# Image Saved to Gallery After Being Captured

Tags: android

Hy,,, this has been confused me for a while since what I intended to do with my app was just to capture images and upload it without saving it into the gallery. But what happen is the opposite.

This is how I call the camera function

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_01);
```

And this is how I handle the request

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if(requestCode == CAMERA_01){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
            byte[] byte_arr = output.toByteArray();
            i11a1 = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
            ((SiteBefore)getActivity().getApplication()).seti11a1(i11a1);
            BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
            img11a1.setBackgroundDrawable(ob);
        }else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
        }
    }
}
```

This code is written inside the fragment class. This cause the image being saved into the gallery. Anyone know what causes this?

Comment: What device are you testing on? Because Samsung devices automatically save all images taken to gallery (or at least they did some years ago when i tried doing the same)

Comment: xiaomi mi 5 @Max90

Comment: Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: i did not find one with the default camera for my case so i used [the openCamera library](https://github.com/almalence/OpenCamera)

Comment: The new photo file is saved to the file system and the media scanner adds this new photo file to the media database on android-5.0 or later. What about deleting the photo after the send (of move it to a hidden ".nomedia" folder)?

Comment: thats good idea but how do the apps figure out which foto has to be deleted since its stored together with other foto

Comment: Why are you using Intent to capture image? I have implemented the same by using Camera2Api. I received ImageReader object from it to which I converted into an image Bitmap and uploaded successfully into my cloud server without saving it into my gallery. I can share the code if needed